# Access other script's references in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

I want to have a single object (Game), that contains references to all other objects (player, chat, console, etc).

I've created those objects and have them referenced in the "Game" object.

Now I want to reference "Game" in some other script and access it's referenced objects through it.

Is that possible?

```
    public class Game : MonoBehaviour
     {
         public GameObject network;
         public GameObject player;
         public GameObject console;
         public GameObject chat;
         public GameObject authentication;
     }
     public class Chat : MonoBehaviour
     {
         public GameObject game;
         string text = game.console.GetComponent<InputField>().text; // gives an error "GameObject'does not contain a definition for 'console'"
     }
```

Comment: you can just create an instance of Game in your other script.  var game = new  Game();  I'd suggest using a singleton pattern though for Game as you most likely only want one

Comment: but that "game" object wont have those references I need, because they are "made" in Unity inspector window via drag-n-dropping

Comment: @JoshAdams You can't instantiate `MonoBehaviour`s that way, Unity will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it should be used like that:

```
string text = game.GetComponent<Game>().console.GetComponent<InputField>().text
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figured it out yourself. If you want to minimize the amount of code you write this is one way of doing it

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField console;
}
public class Chat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Game game;
    string text = game.console.text;
}
```