# Get list from another script in unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I would like to get a value from a serialized list that is on another script. How can I do that? This is my list:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Level
{
    public string Name;
    public Sprite Icon;
    public bool Unlocked;
    public bool Interactable;
}

public List<Level> levelList = new List<Level>();
```

Comment: Is this serialized to xml?

Comment: @3xGuy No, it's not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access other script's references in Unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782267/access-other-scripts-references-in-unity3d)

Comment: @Ruzihm not really :(

Comment: Serialization has nothing to do with accessing list or other items from another script. Serialization is converting from C# type to json, xml (hence the comment about it), yaml, binary or else. Here you want to consider public variables with GetComponent<ComponentType> as the other comment mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put your list inside the scope of the class like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Level {

    public List<Level> levelList = new List<Level>(); //List inside the class

    public string Name;
    public Sprite Icon;
    public bool Unlocked;
    public bool Interactable;
}
```

On your accesor class you need to have a class variable so that you can access that level instance. Then somewhere get the list of that level instance, as in for exmaple in the `Start` of the code below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ListGetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Level level;
    private List<Level> levelList;
    
    void Start()
    {
        levelList = level.levelList; //get level list
    }
}
```

You would need to define how your `Level` instance is created, and the class that holds the instance of the class to provide a more accurate way of accessing the levelList of your `Level` instance, which I think is what you are asking